# Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies, if-statement

Having a bit more trouble with Cookies, I did get my site to save cookies (to-do list items) and reload them after the page had been loaded and place them back into the table on screen.

But, when I deleted all the cookies and tried to start fresh I keep getting a console error saying `Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`  Now, if I comment out the below two sections of code, this problem goes away, but the cookie system will fail of course.

This section checks for the number of items that were in the to-do-list last time someone visited, and sets `i` as that number, so nothing get's deleted.

```
var listCookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var a = 0; a < listCookies.length; a++) {

    var listCount = myCookies[i].trim().split("=");

    if(listCount[0].indexOf("listCount") === 0) {
        var i = listCount;
    } else {
        var i = 0;
    }
 }
```

This section finds the actual to-do's themselves and places them in the table on screen.

```
var myCookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var b = 0; b < myCookies.length; b++) {

    var cookie = myCookies[i].trim().split("=");

    if(cookie[0].indexOf("todo-") === 0) {

        window.todoTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', decodeURIComponent(cookie[1]));
    }
}
```

I understand the issue is that there aren't any cookies saved on someones first visit, but when I tried to add an `if (typeof document.cookie === "undefined")` statement that didn't seem to do anything.

I'm assuming I need an if statement wrapped around these pieces of code right? To say, if there isn't a cookie, 'skip this bit'. If there is, 'do stuff'.

Comment: In the first section you seem to be referencing i and myCookies variables before they were even set. Is that right?  

 var listCount = myCookies[i].trim().split("=");

Comment: Can you check which line caused the error?

Comment: It should be `if (typeof( document.cookie) === "undefined")`.

Comment: `myCookies` is not defined, and `i` is not yet defined, so `myCookies[i]` is asking for `undefined` on `undefined`.

Comment: Why do you need the first section? What do you mean by "nothing gets deleted" ?

Comment: I'm making a to-do-list site, and the to-do's are numbered in the cookies, if someone were to come back and add another it starts off at 0 again, so would delete their first cookie. 

So I needed a way of keeping track of how many items are in their list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` should be global, I have made it `totalCount`.

The first section should be:

```
var totalCount = 0;

var listCookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var a = 0; a < listCookies.length; a++) {

    var listCount = listCookies[a].trim().split("=");

    if(listCount[0].indexOf("listCount") === 0) {
        totalCount = listCount[1];
        break;
    }
 }
```

Second section should be:

```
var myCookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var b = 0; b < myCookies.length; b++) {

    var cookie = myCookies[b].trim().split("=");

    if(cookie[0].indexOf("todo-") === 0) {

        window.todoTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', decodeURIComponent(cookie[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code may be error free, but is it working as you expect?

Comment: Yep! Thank you very much :) My only other thing to figure out is how to remember if a checkbox is checked or not lol.

Comment: You can keep a binary string, each bit for each checkbox.